# How do I call a WCF service from RestSharp

Tags: wcf, xamarin.android, restsharp

Can someone post some sample code to access a WCF service from RestSharp. I am trying to get data into a MonoDroid application and RestSharp seemed pretty simple. However I cannot seem to find any sample code which works. I have hosted the WCF service on my website under shared hosting. I have posted the RestSharp code I am using below but I am getting an error.Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here

```
         var client = new RestClient("http://mysamplesite.com/testService");
        // client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

        var request = new RestRequest("gettestdata", Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("key", ""); 

        // execute the request
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.Content) && response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            DeserialiseData(content);
```

Server Error in Application \"MYSAMPLESITE.COM/TESTSERVICE\"
Internet Information Services 7.5

Error Summary
    HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
          The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Detailed Error Information

IIS Web Core  Error Code 0x80070002 
Requested URL  http://www.mysamplesite.com:80/TestService/GetTestData 
             Physical PathD:\rwq1 \n
       Logon MethodAnonymous \n    Logon UserAnonymous \n
                   Most likely causes: \n   \t

The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
                       The URL contains a typographical error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I tried adding the service file name at the end of the uri path (TestService.svc) and I am receiving an empty string as a response instead of the error above.